# Google App-Engine Java Batch Update

Tags: java, google-app-engine, bigtable, batch-updates

I need to upload a .csv file and save the records in bigtable. 
My application successfully parse 200 records in the csv files and save to table.

Here is my code to save the data.

```
for (int i=0;i<lines.length -1;i++) //lines hold total records in csv file
{
   String line = lines[i]; 

   //The record have 3 columns integer,integer,Text 

   if(line.length() > 15)
   {
 int n = line.indexOf(",");

 if (n>0)
 {
  int ID = lInteger.parseInt(ine.substring(0,n));
  int n1 = line.indexOf(",", n + 2);

  if(n1 > n)
  {
     int Col1 = Integer.parseInt(line.substring(n + 1, n1));
     String Col2 = line.substring(n1 + 1);

     myTable uu = new myTable();

     uu.setId(ID);
     uu.setCol1(MobNo);

     Text t = new Text(Col2);         
     uu.setCol2(t);

       PersistenceManager pm = PMF.get().getPersistenceManager();
            pm.makePersistent(uu);             
     pm.close();
  }
    }
    }
}
```

But when no of records grow it gives timeout error.

The csv file may have upto 800 records. 
Is it possible to do that in App-Engine?

(something like batch update)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

GAE limit you app request to 30 sec, and you can't run long task.

Best approach is to split this CSV into smaller chunks, and process them individually, one after one. In the case when you can upload it only as one big file, you can store it as binary data, and then process (split and parse) using [Task Queue](http://code.google.com/intl/en/appengine/docs/java/taskqueue/) (note that it's also limited to 10 minutes per request, but you can always make a chain of tasks). Or you can user backend to process.

Comment: Great... I was trying to use schedule task which run every minute.. 
Thanks a lot..

Comment: Oh, yes, 3 years there backends wasn't introduced and even Task Queue was limited to 30 seconds. I should update my answer, thanks

Answer (score 0):

You could store your CSV file in the Blobstore ([gzipped](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/dataprocessing/readers_writers#BlobstoreZipLineInputReader) or [not](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/dataprocessing/readers_writers#BlobstoreLineInputReader)) and use a [MapReduce job](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/dataprocessing/overview) to read and persist each line in the Datastore.